# Cannot stop a cloudera/quickstart in Docker

Tags: docker, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I tried to stop a container running [cloudera/quickstart](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html) using

```
docker stop [container]
```

but it is not stopping and is taking forever (nothing happens). Same thing happens if I try to remove it using

```
docker rm -f [container]
```

How can I stop/remove this container? Thanks.

Comment: if you are ok with losing data on that VM, you can do: "killall docker" and "killall docker-machine" to kill docker. But please note that it will kill all docker VMs

Comment: Do you have the right permissions? Try it with `sudo docker stop [container]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside the container then you can execute ctrl+d to come out of it. It will also stop the cloudera container.

Answer (score -1):

You could go into container:

```
docker exec -it {container id} bash
```

then execute `exit`